# system.diagnostic.process refresh returns same process values

Tags: .net, powershell

I have a powershell script that runs various executables. Sometimes an executable will run for a long time and I want to see some process statistics showing that progress is being made (sometime there isn't any progress and I need to stop the current process and restart).

I'm using the [system.diagnostic.process] object to start the process.

```
   $Quiet = $Process.Start()
    if ($Monitor) {
        if (-not $Timeout) { $Timeout = -1 }
        $Process.WaitForExit($Timeout)
        $LastReport = Get-Date
        while (-not $Process.HasExited ) {

            if (((Get-Date) - $LastReport).Minutes -gt 2) {
                $Process.Refresh()
                if (-not ($Process.HasExited)) {
                    Write-Host "    Physical memory usage: $($Process.WorkingSet64)"
                    Write-Host "    Base priority: $($Process.BasePriority)"
                    Write-Host "    User processor time: $($Process.UserProcessorTime)"
                    Write-Host "    Privileged processor time: $($Process.PrivilegedProcessorTime)"
                    Write-Host "    Total processor time: $($Process.TotalProcessorTime)"
                    Write-Host "    Page Memory Size: $($Process.PagedMemorySize64)"

                    if ($Process.Responding) {
                        Write-Host "  Status = Running"
                    } else {
                        Write-Host "  Status = Not Responding"
                    }
                }
                $LastReport = Get-Date
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I run the script I get the same results over and over:

```
   Physical memory usage: 8605696
    Base priority: 8
    User processor time: 00:00:00.0624004
    Privileged processor time: 00:00:00.0624004
    Total processor time: 00:00:00.1248008
    Page Memory Size: 3653632
  Status = Running
    Physical memory usage: 8605696
    Base priority: 8
    User processor time: 00:00:00.0624004
    Privileged processor time: 00:00:00.0624004
    Total processor time: 00:00:00.1248008
    Page Memory Size: 3653632
  Status = Running
```

How can I add function to my code to assure me that the process is in fact running and not stuck.

Note that this script is run remotely and I rely on the returned stdout contents to monitor the running of my executables.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the answer, but too long now for a comment.

The way your are polling your process is not so good. your *while loop* is always running, consuming processor. In spite of using your test of two minutes elapsed time just use Start-Sleep (120). Using Start-Process CmdLet your code seams to work.

This Works well, just start a `dir /s` inside the `cmd.exe` from the root of you system directory to test :

```
$process = Start-Process cmd.exe -PassThru
$Process.WaitForExit(1)
while (-not $Process.HasExited )
{
  Start-Sleep (3)

  Write-Host "    Physical memory usage: $($Process.WorkingSet64)"
  Write-Host "    Base priority: $($Process.BasePriority)"
  Write-Host "    User processor time: $($Process.UserProcessorTime)"
  Write-Host "    Privileged processor time: $($Process.PrivilegedProcessorTime)"
  Write-Host "    Total processor time: $($Process.TotalProcessorTime)"
  Write-Host "    Page Memory Size: $($Process.PagedMemorySize64)"

  if ($Process.Responding)
  {
    Write-Host "  Status = Running"
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Host "  Status = Not Responding"
  }
}
```